# Why can't i call a method to the parent activity from a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment where I wish to call a method from the FragmentActivity that contains this fragment. I defined a method in FragmentTabs(extends FragmentActivity) that sets the lastTab fragment on a specific event in the fragment.
For some reason getActivity().SomeUserDefinedActivity() cannot be resolved.

Here is the code explaining my problem :

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    testButton = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
    testButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Log.i("FragmentTest", "Button1 Clicked");


            TestFragment2 f2 = new TestFragment2();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, f2);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
            // This is where I want to call FragmentTabs method SetLastFragment, but I cannot access it.
            getActivity().SetLastFragment(f2);

        }
    });
}
```

This is the method I wish to call in FragmentTabs:

```
    public void SetLastFragment(Fragment f)
{
    mTabManager.SetLastTabFragment(f);
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`getActivity()` returns just an Activity instance. This can be any activity that embeds your fragment. `SetLastFragment()` is a method of one specific activity of yours, named `FragmentTabs`. Not all activities have this method.

Which means you have to cast it to your specific activity class. If you use your fragment in multiple activties, you should also check if the correct activity is used, e.g. via the `instanceof` operator:

```
Activity a = getActivity();

if(a instanceof FragmentTabs) {
    ((FragmentTabs) a).SetLastFragment(f2);
}
```

Comment: Also in general: *"does not work"* is not a very specific problem description. Please post the error messages that you get, in this case probably "The method X is undefined for class Y" or a similar message. Here I had an idea what's up, but that won't be always the case. Some things are hard to find without the message.

Comment: @litemode: Even better is to not call a method on the activity at all. If you are using fragments, there is a good chance that your fragment may be hosted by more than one activity (e.g., one for smaller screens, one for larger screens). The most flexibility is to use a listener interface, supplied to the fragment. The second-most flexibility is to say that the activity implements an interface and cast `getActivity()` to that interface.

Comment: I agree with CommonsWare that you should use interface to handle events. However, directly calling the activity's methods like the answer above is useful when you have nested fragments, wherein an activity adds a fragment which in turn adds another fragment and so on. Its easier to access the activity's methods that way rather than to implement interfaces in each fragment to be able to reach to the activity.